Center of outer Soddy circle lies on the same side of lines $AC,BC$ where $AB$ is the longest side
Let $AB$ be the longest side of $\triangle ABC$.
I want to prove the center of outer Soddy circle either lies on the intersection of the inner sides of lines $AC,BC$ or lie on the intersection of the outer sides of lines $AC,BC$ (Take the side containing the triangle as the inner side of line $AC,BC$.).
So I need to prove the signed distances of X175 to $AC,BC$ are of the same sign.

The trilinear coordinates (The ratio of signed distances between $X_{175}$ and sides $BC,CA,AB$): $$-1 + \sec \frac A2 \cos \frac B2 \cos \frac C2:-1 + \sec \frac B2 \cos \frac C2 \cos \frac A2:-1 + \sec \frac C2 \cos \frac A2 \cos \frac B2$$
Since $AB$ is the longest side, $C$ is the largest internal angle, so $C>A$ and $C>B$.
Since $\cos\frac C2 \cos\frac B2\le \cos\frac C2<\cos\frac A2$,
$$-1+\sec\frac A2 \cos\frac C2 \cos\frac B2<0$$
Since $\cos\frac C2 \cos\frac A2\le \cos\frac C2<\cos\frac B2$,
$$-1+\sec\frac B2 \cos\frac C2 \cos\frac A2<0$$
So the signed distances between $X_{175}$ and sides $BC,CA$ are of the same sign.
